# Showing "diaplay_name"

Tags: email

For my email notification, I am trying to customize it so that the email shows `display_name`

Here is the original code that shows the `from name`:

```
   public function get_from_name() {
    return wp_specialchars_decode( esc_html( get_option( 'woocommerce_email_from_name' ) ), ENT_QUOTES );
   }
```

Here is what I am trying to incorporate so that it shows `display_name` instead:

```
 global $userpro;
 <?php echo userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id); ?>
```

How can I change the original code so that it shows the `display_name` instead?

Thanks bunch!

Steve

Comment: Well the exact problem right here is the `$user_id`. The WooCommerce method you have provided doesn't use any `$user_id` parameter, and without the id, you can't fetch the display name.

Comment: I know this is not correct but could you see if this will work? 
`public function get_from_name() {
   global $userpro, $user_id;
return $this->object->billing_first_name . ' ' . $this->object->('display_name', $user_id);
 }`